# jQuery file upload and save without server side

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

can you please acknowledge me if there is a way to create a simple file uploader with jQuery and save that file (image) in some folder ... without the use of any server side scripting such as php etc.
Here is some simple script i tried so far

```
 $(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
    var file_data = $("#avatar").prop("files")[0]; 
    var form_data = new FormData(); 
    form_data.append("file", file_data);
    $.ajax({
                url: "/img",
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post'
       });
});
```

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar" />
    <button id="upload" value="Upload">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you require to have serverside code , as jquery is client side script , it can send data to server and on serverside you need script which perform operation on data you sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery being JavaScript- no way for it to write to the file system. It needs to use REST API to do writes and other server side operations like interacting with db etc.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/README.md

Having said that, here is PHP sample/code to process the file.

https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form

Comment: any other way of doing it without involving any server side language? the end user will simply be using the offline html file in my case and will be saving the image file in the img folder in there drive

Comment: I see. Then perhaps then there is a design issue to think about because the language of choice doesn’t support that requirement

Comment: The offline thing is a big limitation to even use something like google forms

Comment: friend my end user do not have any IIS, WAMP etc they are simply going to work on a file and finally the html and images will be saved as zip file ... i cant use php or any other :(

Comment: Thanks. If the original question is answered don’t forget to mark it answered